# Checking database values

Tags: android, sqlite, firebase

When creating an android application that has data we can use some ways to store the data example: `sharedPreferences`, `read/write to file`, `sqlite database` and `firebase`.

Im wondering if i create an sqlite database (create tables,columns..) how can i see the values that the user is entering in the database table. Example, in web development we can use phpmyadmin to check all the tables and data entered in each column. Is there a way to do that if using sqlite database or firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the firebase, you just go to the console, choose "database" on the left-side menu, and expand the child nodes of the DB (see attached snapshot).

For SQLite - there are several solutions, one of them is here:
http://sqlitebrowser.org/
Also, there is extension to Chrome browser.

Hope it helps.

[image]

Comment: This is link to chrome extension to view SQLite:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sqlite-viewer-with-google/aaeojgplhedihcdhfcgodiepddeecepl

Comment: which is better to use `firebase` or `sqlite`?

Comment: Briefly, it's up to your needs. SQLite is local storage, that is not dependent on internet connection. While Firebase is server-side. So, if the data of your app is needed be synced-up with other devices, or users, or backed-up, or so - Firebase can serve it. Also, it provides event listeners to immediately retrieve new or changed data (say, to chat app). But, alternatively,  you can use SQLite and sync the data up with, say, MySQL -need server-side coding here. 
I afraid this discussion can be moderated as off-topic, though :))

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way to see debug values. Use [this](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database) library

```
debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Facebook Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) which is very useful for querying & modifying your shared preferences & sqlite database.

All you have to do is add the following dependency in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.1.1'
```

Then initialize stetho in your Application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
      public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

     // Create an InitializerBuilder
    Stetho.InitializerBuilder initializerBuilder = 
            Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this);

    // Enable Chrome DevTools
    initializerBuilder.enableWebKitInspector(
            Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this)
    );

    // Enable command line interface
    initializerBuilder.enableDumpapp(
            Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(context)
    );

    // Use the InitializerBuilder to generate an Initializer
    Stetho.Initializer initializer = initializerBuilder.build();

    // Initialize Stetho with the Initializer
    Stetho.initialize(initializer);
  }
}
```

Then run your app and open chrome developer tools

```
chrome://inspect
```

From here you can view and edit your apps Shared Prefrences and Sqlite Datebase. Stetho is not limited to these functionalities, there's much more [you can do with it.](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/debugging-android-apps-with-facebooks-stetho--cms-24205)